# My internet changes ip, what can I do?

Tags: networking

I live in a student dorm, where internet is provided from the wall. I have noticed that my IP address changes frequently during the day, which causes my online playing to freeze.

Needless to say, it's very frustrating. The internet in my house is using some mikrotik service.

I read here 
[My home IP appears to change every second or two. What can I do?](https://superuser.com/questions/1124145/my-home-ip-appears-to-change-every-second-or-two-what-can-i-do)
That there seems not the be anything I can do.

Is there a way that I can set a timer so I can be warned 5 minutes before the IP address will change?

I'm thinking that maybe this doesn't happen at random, and then I could measure how frequently it happens.

Comment: As for a solution.  Talk to the school IT Administrator.  Because only they can determine if something is happening that shouldn't happen.  Your lease on your up address shouldn't happening multiple times a day.

Comment: Im not familiar with the term masked profanity. I was just thinking, that it might be able to from my computer see when the ip adress changes, what triggers is. If this is what you referring to as not acceptable, my apologies, I was not aware. There is not IT administrator here. Someone built the network when the house was built and thats it. @Ramhound

Comment: It's profanity but instead of actually spelling the entire word, you mask some of the characters, the use of the masked word is still vulgar all the same.  If you cannot Administrate the network then this problem cannot be solved

Comment: If you have DHCP enabled, turn it off and specify a static IP in your personal device's networking options.

Comment: But which ip should I specify? For dns I could use google dns or what do you mean? @MrPublic

Comment: You are correct and I shouldnt have done that. @Ramhound

Comment: @mrpublic You need to be careful in doing this as you can cause a conflict if the DHCP server trust to assign that IP to something else. You should assign the static outside the range set aside for dynamic allocation.

Comment: @davidgo Yes, that is correct. Like others have mentioned, just ask a Network Administrator and they should be able to provide you will all the information you will need for setting up a Static IP.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution if you are in a dorm environment would be to speak to the it people, explain your issue and ask them to allocate you a static IP.

The rest of what I have to say is speculative, could breach terms of service and have other unintended consequences. I mention it because understanding these things can be useful in working out how to legitimately resolve your issues.

First off, you should clarify if the problem is your world apparent IP or if you are behind NAT and your RFC1918 (private) IP is changing.

If your world apparent IP changes you need to look to your upstream providers and discover if they have an issue or if it's a side effect of multiple gateways - in which case they need to change there routing.

If it's happening on the private IP, there is most likely an issue of the range of ips being set aside being less then the number of clients, and should be increased. It may be possible to reduce this range and to statically assign yourself an IP in the same network but outside the DHCP range - normally near the top or bottom of the range. If you do this without coordinating with the admin it can cause things to break.

** A partial solution to either issue is to use a UDP based VPN (most VPNs use UDP   **  with a provider that will provide a static IP.  This won't fix the problem, but will reduce it - the VPN will go down and come back up - when it comes up though, your IP will be the same, reducing the game servers confusion and downtime.

Comment: "First off, you should clarify if the problem is your world apparent IP or if you are behind NAT and your RFC1918 (private) IP is changing." I'm sorry, but how can I gather this information?

Comment: @Olba12 You must have already gathered it. You said, "I have noticed that my IP address changes frequently during the day". You must have done this *somehow*, right? You just forgot to tell us.

Comment: Ah everytime I get kicked out of the game, and try to go back to my character. It tells me that my ip has changed, and in order to play, I need to sign off. Then relogg as usual again.

Comment: This means it's likely your EXTERNAL IP is changing. To check this, go to www.whatismyip.com before you game, and again when you are kicked. Using a VPN will probably allow you to continue without the server thinking your IP has changed.

Comment: @davidgo what kind of vpn do you have in mind? Isnt there a risk that the vpn increases lag? For the specific game I play there is also tunnel service you can buy. Its a service who decreases your latency/ping. I dont know if this could work?

Comment: I can't provide you definitive answers. I am very skeptical of a tunnel service that purports to reduce lag (its possible in some, but not most cases).   If the VPN is UDP based you should try it.   VPN's will normally increase lag.  This increase can be minimised by finding a VPN provider close to you.  I'm thinking of a VPN based on the OpenVPN protocol - I do not have a service provider recommendation (as I role my own)

Comment: I have tried the tunnel service (free trial) and it reduced ping/latency with 70 % by rerouting connection to server. I will look into a VPN provider. Thank you. @davidgo

Comment: @davidgo I did as you said, I went to whatsismyip website! And the ip is changing, but also (according to the site) my ISP is also changing?!

Comment: In that case I expect that the facilities provided to your dorm are provided by more then 1 provider using some kind of load balancing router, so the router is regularly switching your path through different links with different ISPs.   A correctly configured OpenVPN tunnel will fix your apparent problem, but you should also approach your provider and ask them to change their load balancing schema in  such a way that your IP does not change as frequently.